# Moving from multiple local git clones or repositories to a single worktree based instance

Tags: git

How can I best merge together my multiple local git clones of a repository and all of its local branches tags and stashes into a consolidated local repository to worktree out of?

They are all copies of the same repository that were kept separate & syncing with the repo server for parallel work on different issues.  Their local content has drifted apart for some time and I would like to preserve all of that.

In the past the git integrations in older versions of Visual Studio did not understand worktrees which has lead to me avoiding that useful feature for some time but now that is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you regularly push branches to a central repo, then just either `git clone` that repo or `git fetch` it into any one of your existing clones. Then use [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) to add worktrees to your single local repo. If you have any local changes that aren't committed, then you will have to copy those over, either manually or write a script to do it.